# Warning Message Accepted from Command Line Batch File

Tags: windows, command-line, message

I am new to using batch files in order to automate some of our application functions.

What I'm trying to do is schedule an import utility using the command provided. However, the utility checks out a license from a license server and then loads on the workstation. What is happening is I sometimes get a warning message if a license is about to expire (within 30 days), and thus the import will not start until the user inputs an "OK" command on the warning message prompted.

I would like a way to automate the "OK" click when running the batch file, as this would ensure that the import takes place as scheduled.

The import command is:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartPlant\Electrical\Program\SPELImportManager.exe" /G inassociate
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked a lot with SPEL, but have you checked that the importer doesn't have a quiet option? Something similar to /Q?